# Getting Errors where there should be none

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors, element

I do not know why I am being asked to place commas where periods should be. const cards is saying I can't set it there when this is the way to set a variable.

I have tried to change from const to let and restructure .forEach syntax

```
class TabLink {
    constructor(tabElement) {
        // assign this.tabElement to the tabElement DOM reference
        this.tabElement = tabElement;

        // Get the `data-tab` value from this.tabElement and store it here
        this.tabData = this.tabElement.dataset.tab;

        // We need to find out if a user clicked 'all' cards or a specific category.  Follow the instructions below to accomplish this task:    

        // Check to see if this.tabData is equal to 'all'
        if (this.tabElement.dataset.tab === "all") {
            // If `all` is true, select all cards regardless of their data attribute values
            this.cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
        } else {
            // else if `all` is false, only select the cards with matching this.tabData values
            this.cards = document.querySelectorAll(`.card[tabData="${this.tabData}"]`);
        }

        // Map over the newly converted NodeList we just created in our if statement above. Convert each this.cards element into a new instance of the TabCard class. Pass in a card object to the TabCard class. 
        this.cards = Array.from(this.cards).map((card) => new TabCard(card));


        // Add a click event that invokes this.selectTab
        this.tabElement.addEventListener('click', () => { this.selectTab() });
    }

    selectTab() {

            // Select all elements with the .tab class on them
            // const tabs = document.querySelectorAll();
            const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

            // Iterate through the NodeList removing the .active-tab class from each element
            Array.from(tabs).forEach((tabs))
            link.classList.remove(".active-tab");
        }
        // 

    // Select all of the elements with the .card class on them
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

    // Iterate through the NodeList setting the display style each one to 'none'
    cards.forEach(card => {
        card.style.display = "none";
    })

    // Add a class of ".active-tab" to this.tabElement
    this.tabElement = ".active-tab";

    // Notice we are looping through the this.cards array and invoking selectCard() from the TabCard class. Just un-comment the code and study what is happening here.
    this.cards.forEach(card => card.selectCard());
    console.log(this.cards);
}
```

'const' can only be used in a .ts file.
';' expected.
',' expected.
',' expected.
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: That's still inside the body of the class, you can't define a `const` there. *"A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected"*, because they're the things you can have in a class body.

Comment: So what do I do? this was only un-commented and was pre-added to the assignment...

Comment: Put it outside the class or inside a method. It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, so you'll have to figure that part out for yourself.

Comment: Says what I am trying to achieve in the commented out sections

Comment: Everything after the `selectTab()` method needs to go inside the `constructor()`

Comment: Since you're using `document.querySelectorAll` just put this in the initialization section of your code. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn. That helped.

Comment: Thank you @shadoe2020 yours helped as well.